# Rails: Find relations on relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't believe I haven't come up with a good solution to this common problem after 5 years of Rails-programming. Also, I assume there are 100's of answers to this particular question but I don't know the definitions (relations? associations? etc) to search it well. So here we go:

I have two models: Categories and Products and a CategoryProductRelation-model to tie them together.

Category-model:

```
has_many :category_product_relations
has_many :products, :through => :category_product_relations
```

CategoryProductRelation-model:

```
has_many :products
has_many :categories
```

Category typically has some 1000 products.

### The problem

Very often I need to do searches like "All products in the Food type of categories" i.e. Categories: 'Fruits' (1), 'Cereal' (2), 'Meat'(3).

Basically, what I would *like* to do is something like `Category.where(:id => [1,2,3]).products` which obviously doesn't work.

### My (slow) solution

What I often do is something like this:

```
products = Product.where(:id => CategoryProductRelation.where(:category_id => [1,2,3]).pluck(:product_id))
```

which works, mostly fine as well. However, this is very slow if the amount of products is large resulting in 400ms queries!

There **has** to be a smarter way, right? This feels like Rails 101 but I can't figure it out in a way that is simple and **fast**!

Lastly, iterating through Category like:

```
Category.where(:id => [1,2,3]).each do |category|
category.products 
#...and so on
end
```

seems to be equally slow.

Is there a magic bullet to this common problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `merge`?

```
Product.joins(:categories).merge(Category.where(:id => [1,2,3])).pluck(:id)
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge

> Merges in the conditions from other, if other is an
>   ActiveRecord::Relation

Comment: This seems to be the best solution so far. It does not create the dreaded Product.where(:id => 1,2,3,...7000) that I assume will use a lot of memory in the db. It is still almost as slow though (which surprises me). However, by adding a .limit to it I can speed it up significantly. .limit(1) = 2.8 ms, limit(50)=3.9ms, limit(500)=11.5ms, limit(5000) = 74ms, no limit (i.e. 7000) = 100 ms.

Comment: Tested it some more and this seems to be the best solution to my problem. I guess what is unique in my situation is that I have a relation model that makes things a bit more complicated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[`includes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) should help. Didn't test, but something like:

```
Category.includes(:products).where(id: [1, 2, 3]).flat_map(&:products)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works in terms of code but I have two follow up questions to this. 1. I need the result to be an ActiveRecord (not an array), is there a way to do that? 2. If I want to add filter on Products like ("products.active"), how would I do that with this solution?

Comment: 2. The linked documentation clearly shows, with an example, what to do about conditions on included tables. 1. Just don't `flat_map` then.

Comment: 1. If I don't use flat_map how do I get the products out of that query, then?

Comment: 2. I didn't actually realize that it was a link. Will look it up.

Comment: If you don't want an array of `Product` or an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, I don't know what you do want.

Comment: But I DO want an ActiveRecord::Relation. I am not 100% sure though. I want the same type of result as one get with a Product.where(:foo => 'bar')

Comment: When I test your solution it actually seems like it is creating the same type of query (albeit more elegantly) in terms that I get a Product.where(:id => 1,2,3,...7000) which is just as slow.

Comment: The reason I can't use an array output is because I need to add where-filters etc on the result, like "products.where(:foo => 'bar')

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this works in your case. I use mongoid so i do something like this.

```
Product.where(:category_id.in => [1,2,3])
```

This gives me all the products with the categories whose ids are 1,2,3.

For Product model

```
belongs_to :category
```

For Category model

```
has_many :products
```

I hope you get an idea.

For two queries you can do something like this.

```
category_product_relations_ids = CategoryProductRelation.where(:category_ids => [1,2,3]).pluck(:id)
Product.where(:category_product_relation_id => category_product_relations_ids)
```

Comment: This won't really work since I have a CategoryProductRelation in between. Basically, Product does not have a :category_id attribute. Is there another way around it?

Comment: I think then you need at least 2 queries to do it.

Comment: Most likely, but I can't seem to get my head around how. I tested and it seems like the category_id.in won't work either but I think this would be the same as Product.where(:category_id => [1,2,3]). I can't see the difference actually.

Comment: O yes its same .. I told you i use mongoid. Mongoid requires .in for finding in array.

Comment: Thanks, this works but is basically the same solution as the one I have. My three categories has apprx 7.000 products which creates a query similar to Product.where(:id => 1,2,3,4,5,6...7000) which takes about 100-200 ms. Perhaps the question is, should it take that long or is it actually an indexing question? The CategoryProductRelation is properly indexed though.

Comment: I think indexing Product should also help reducing time. Also you use mysql i think. You can use joins. Its powerful. I usually work with document based dbs for big data, these dbs are already faster for these kind of queries.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the indexes and they seem alright. Btw I am using postgresql. How would I use joins in your solution?

Comment: If you are using Mongiod I would recommend building has_and_belongs_to_many :products, index: true and has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, index: true in both models and avoiding a lookup table.  It will be fast however since category will have many products, product_ids array will get very large.

Answer (score 1):

The magic word is database join.
To use it, you need to think a little in the opposite direction.
You ask for products with conditions on a joined table.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

specificly look for: "12.3. 12.3 Specifying Conditions on the Joined Tables"

So it is something like

```
Products.joins(:category_product_relations).
  where( category_product_relations: {category_id: [1,2,3]} )
```

Comment: Thanks, my gut feeling is that this is the way to go. I will look it up and get back.